# Law of total probability for continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I would like your help to rewrite an expression involving the law of total probability with continuous random variables.

Consider the random variables $Y,V,T$ with supports $\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{V},\mathcal{T}$. Only $\mathcal{Y}$ is finite, the other two sets are non-finite.

What I want to do is to rewrite the probability distribution of $(Y,V)$ as a function of the probability distributions $P_V$, $P_{T}(\cdot| V)$, $P_{Y}(\cdot| T)$.

If $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ were finite, then we would have had that $\forall y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\forall v\in \mathcal{V}$

$$
P_{Y,V}(y,v)=P_V(v)\times \sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}} P_T(t|v) \times P_Y(y|t,v)
$$

I'm unable to rewrite this expression when $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ are not finite. I don't want to use densities, but just cumulative distribution functions. Could you help?

Comment: Unless you want to use the cumulative distribution functions's derivative, you won't be able to!

Comment: Thanks, which means that I have to use densities? With densities the expression is simply $f_{Y,V}(y,v)=f_V(v)\times \int_{\mathcal{T}} f_T(t|v) P_Y(y|t,v)dt$? If wrong, could you suggest a correct expression using derivatives of CDF or densities?

Comment: Your expresion is right, and the derivaitve of a CDF is precisely a density function!

Comment: Do you actually know what the expression $P(\cdot|V)$ means when $V$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: We can describe $P(\cdot|V)$ rigorously in terms of regular conditional probabilities for general $V$. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability).